# Convert Int32.Maximum+ valued number to int32

Tags: c#

I want to covert a big number, which is bigger than int32 maximum range - to int32 using C#. So that if it is over than maximum range 2147483647, then it will start again from -2147483648. For now I am doing this like :

```
long val = 3903086636L;
long rem = val % 2147483648L;
long div = val / 2147483648L;
int result = div % 2 == 0 ? (int)rem - 1 : -2147483648 + (int)rem;
```

I am not sure that if I doing this correctly. Is there any utility function or quick way to doing this in C# ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have [checked mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/khy08726.aspx) enabled, just casting it will handle the overflow as you expect:

```
int i = (int)val;
```

Or, as suggested by Matthew Watson, to make it compiler-setting independent:

```
int i = unchecked((int)val);
```

This will not throw an exception. The integer will overflow and continue counting from `int.MinValue`.

Proof:

```
long val = (long)int.MaxValue + 1;
int result = (int)val;

Console.WriteLine(result == int.MinValue); // true
```

Comment: Will it affect my application if I disable checked mode ?

Comment: By default it is disabled, so no.

Comment: Or you could write `int i = unchecked((int)val);` and it will work regardless of the compiler's `checked` setting.

Comment: Used int int1 = unchecked((int)dec1); but still showing this error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32". dec1 is a decimal and value 3903086624M.

Comment: Your question has a long, why use a decimal all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply add the rest to `int.MinValue`:

```
long tmp = myValue - int.MaxValue;
while(tmp > int.MaxValue) tmp -= int.MaxValue;

if (tmp > 0) tmp = int.MinValue + tmp;
```

The loop preserves that you can work on numbers that are also greater then `2 * int.MaxValue`.

If you use this and test with `myValue = 3 * int.MaxValue + 1` you will get `2147483647` as result.

Comment: what if `myValue` equals `4*int.MaxValue`?

Comment: @Wimmel good point, I guess we need a loop in this case, will update this soon.

Comment: If `myValue` equals `int.MaxValue+1`, I believe the result should be `int.MinValue` and not `int.MinValue+1`. If `myValue` equals `2*int.MaxValue+2`, I believe the result should be `0` and not `int.MinValue+2`.